# Does the Google Feed API have domain/URL restrictions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

The sites we build at my company often have blogs, and we sometimes like to show excerpts from the blog feeds on the homepages. In the past I have used jQuery and the Google Feed API with great success to access the blog RSS and display the excerpts. But recently we changed our dev/QA URL schema, and now I can't get the RSS feeds to load on our test sites.

Our dev/QA urls look like this now: `sitename.dev.aztekhq.com` or `sitename.qa.aztekhq.com`. The blog feed is always `/blog/syndication.axd` (we use BlogEngine.NET).

I am using https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss for the jQuery plugin to the Google API.

What I have determined through testing so far:

- Loading a feed from a live blog works. Loading from a dev or QA site does not. This has been determined both on sites I am developing and also through the Google Feed API playground, so I know it's not something I did wrong with the script.
- I can access the dev/QA feeds through my browser, and I can also subscribe to them using an RSS reader, so I know the feeds are working.

Is it because of the way our dev/qa URLs are structured? I'm kind of at a loss here. I hope this is clear. If not, I can provide more information

Comment: If you can't get it to work with Google, check our Superfeedr's API too: http://blog.superfeedr.com/jquery-superfeedr/

Answer (score 0):

The Google Feed API was getting a 400 when it hit our servers, for reasons unknown to me. I was able to roll a very simple RSS parser using the jQuery ajax() function. It's probably not the most robust thing, but it gets the data without returning a 400.